# Get last element of vector

Tags: c++, object, vector, return

I have 2 methods in my class .cpp file:

`getDoctorAt()` which takes int ant return element at that position

```
Doctor Hospital::getDoctorAt(const int pos) const {
    if ((pos >= 0) && (pos < implHospital->doctors.size()))
        return implHospital->doctors[pos];
    else
        throw out_of_range("Index out of bounds");
}
```

And `getLastPatient()` which should return last element or which added last to vector

```
Patient Hospital::getLastPatient() {
    //int pos = implHospital->patients.size()-1;
    return implHospital->patients.back();
}
```

But the `getLastPatient()` doesn't work, program crashes if executed.

```
cout << h.getDoctorAt(2) << endl; // ok!
cout << h.getLastPatient() << endl; // crashes program
```

Any ideas why? Don't want to post full code, quite long.

Comment: You do know that [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) already has an [access function which does bounds checking](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably your `patients` vector is empty. Calling `back()` on an empty container causes undefined behavior.